# Relation between beta and gamma function by an elementary method :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

Consider the integral :$\int_0^1 {(tx+1-x)^n}dx$,n $\epsilon $ N and t is a parameter.
Then, $$\int_0^1 {(tx+1-x)^n}dx=\frac{{t}^{n+1}-1}{{(n+1)}{(t-1)}}=\frac{[t^{n}+t^{n-1}+....+t+1]}{n+1}-----1$$
But,$${(tx+(1-x))^n}=\binom{n}{0}(tx)^n+\binom{n}{1}(tx)^{n-1}(1-x)+\binom{n}{2}(tx)^{n-2}(1-x)^2+...+\binom{n}{k}(tx)^{n-k}(1-x)^k+...+\binom{n}{n}(1-x)^n$$
So,$$\int_0^1 {(tx+1-x)^n}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(tx)^{n-k}.(1-x)^kdx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^{n-k}\int_0^1\binom{n}{k}.x^{n-k}(1-x)^kdx$$
using 1 :$$\frac{[t^{n}+t^{n-1}+....+t+1]}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^{n-k}\int_0^1\binom{n}{k}.x^{n-k}(1-x)^kdx$$
Equating coefficients of $t^{n-k}$ on both sides:
$$\frac{1}{n+1}=\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1x^{n-k}(1-x)^kdx=\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1(1-x)^{n-k}x^kdx$$
Hence,$$\int_0^1x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}dx=\frac{1}{(n+1){\binom{n}{k}}}$$By taking $k=\alpha-1,n-k=\beta-1:$
$$B(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=\frac{{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)}}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Can anyone suggest me  some other elementary methods for this that doesn't  involves convolutions or double integrals ??