# Beta-gamma integrals

Tags: beta-function

I know that $B (m,n) =\frac{\Gamma (m) \Gamma (n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$.

But  $B (m,m)$ = $2^{1-2m} B(m, 1/2)  $, I didn't get how this equation arrived, I tried applying the formula but cant obtain all the terms.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/proving-and-deriving-a-gamma-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the duplication formula $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(x+1/2) = 2^{1-2x} \Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(2x)$ found  [in the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) it can be seen that
\begin{align}
B(m,m) &= \frac{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(2m)} = \frac{\Gamma(m) \, 2^{1-2m} \Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(m+1/2)} = 2^{1-2m} \, B\left(m , \frac{1}{2}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Well done!  a +1.